# How to perform modular

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you solve this kind of mod when $x<n$ in 
$$x \bmod(n)$$
The other day I was looking at this $ 2 \bmod(7) = 2$ . How is this even possible since there will be no remainder or its always $0$ in these cases.  I looked at other similar answers but no one ever went through the key concept.  Forgive me if I am missing the obvious fact.

Comment: $2=0\cdot 7+2$, so the remainder when $2$ is divided by $7$ is $2$ and the quotient is $0$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#Integer_division).

Comment: @user26486 How did you get 2 at the beginning. Is it $numerator= (0*denominator)+ remainder $ ?

Comment: $\text{dividend}=\text{quotient}\times\text{divisor}+\text{remainder}$.

Comment: @user26486 Thanx a lot! I remember doing this in 3rd grade but I had a robot mind back then! Anyhow, thanx for being explicit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n > 2$.  A theorem called the division algorithm guarantees that you can write an integer $x$ as

$x = qn + r$, where $r$ is greater than or equal to zero but strictly less than $n$.

When you write $x$ in this way, we say $x \pmod n = r$.  In other words, $x \pmod n$ is the remainder you get after dividing by $n$.

When $x$ is less than $n$ (and non negative), then $x = 0n + x$, and so the remainder is just $x$.

Thus, $x \pmod n = x$ in this case.